# c#- Corrupt file when writing to Response

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, iis

I am trying to write a file to the output response stream using ASP.Net. When I download the file, I get a `Errors were found opening .zip file. You can extract files from this archive, but other programs may not be able to open it. Do you want to try fixing the problems?` error. I am however able to cancel this and open the zip file correctly.

What could I be doing wrong?

**ASP.Net\C# code:**

```
var pathToFile = "c:\abc.zip";
string fileName = Path.GetFileName(pathToFile);
byte[] buffer;
using (var fileStream = new FileStream(pathToFile, Filemode.open))
{
  buffer = new byte[fileStream. Length];
  fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, (int)fileStream.Length);
}
Response.Clear();
Response.Buffer = true;
Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", string.Format(@"attachment; filename={0}.zip", filename));
Response.ContentType = "application/zip";
Response.AppendHeader("content-length", buffer.Length.ToString());
Response.WriteFile(pathToFile);
```

Comment: you might not be reading the full file. also theres no need to store it in a buffer - you can have the response write directly.

Comment: I was previously writing to the response directly without appending the content-length in the response header but was getting the same error. How do I ensure that "I read the full file"?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use `buffer` and write file to user, do not use `Response.WriteFile`.

Change to `Response.OutputStream.Write`, and modify your codes, like this:

```cs
var pathToFile = "c:\abc.zip";
string fileName = Path.GetFileName(pathToFile);
byte[] buffer = new byte[0];
using (var fileStream = new FileStream(pathToFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
  buffer = new byte[fileStream.Length];
  fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
}
Response.Clear();
Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", string.Format(@"attachment; filename={0}", filename));
Response.ContentType = "application/zip";
Response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
Response.Flush();
Response.End();
```